# Lightning Messaging Service, Send data Bidirectionally using one Messaging Channel

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

Hi I am trying to send information from Component A to Component X and X to A. I was able to first get the data to send from A to X however upon implementing X to A (which works) A to X no longer works. Is this due to the subscribe function in Component A overwriting the Subscription in Component X?

Component A HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC LMS Component A">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter message to publish" onkeyup={inputHandler}></lightning-input>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="Publish" onclick={publishMessage}></lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            Number recieved from X: <strong>{recievedData}</strong>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Component A JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, wire  } from 'lwc';
import SAMPLEMC from "@salesforce/messageChannel/SampleMessageChannel__c"
import { MessageContext, publish, subscribe, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from 'lightning/messageService';

export default class LmsComponentA extends LightningElement {
    inputValue
    recievedData
    subcription

    @wire(MessageContext)
    context

    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscribeTransfer()
    }

    inputHandler(event){
        this.inputValue = event.target.value
    }

    subscribeTransfer(){
        this.subcription = subscribe(this.context, SAMPLEMC, (data)=>{this.recievedData = data.xToAData.receivedNum}, {scope:APPLICATION_SCOPE})
    }

    publishMessage(){
        const message ={
            lmsData:{
                value:this.inputValue
            }
        }
        publish(this.context, SAMPLEMC, message)
    }
}
```

Component X HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC LMS Component X">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="unsubscribe" onclick={unsubscribeMessage}></lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            Message Recieved: <strong>{recievedMessage}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="number" label="Enter a number" class="number-input"></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" title="Publish To A" onclick={publishNumber} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Component X JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import SAMPLEMC from "@salesforce/messageChannel/SampleMessageChannel__c"
import { subscribe, MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE, unsubscribe, publish } from 'lightning/messageService';

export default class LmsComponentX extends LightningElement {
    recievedMessage
    subcription

    @wire(MessageContext)
    context

    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscribeMessage()
    }

    subscribeMessage(){
        this.subcription = subscribe(this.context, SAMPLEMC, (message)=>{this.handleMessage(message)}, {scope:APPLICATION_SCOPE})
    }

    handleMessage(message){
        this.recievedMessage = message.lmsData.value ? message.lmsData.value : 'NO Message published'
    }

    unsubscribeMessage(){
        unsubscribe(this.subcription)
        this.subcription = null
    }

    publishNumber(){
        const data = {
            xToAData:{
                receivedNum:this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").value
            }
        }
        publish(this.context, SAMPLEMC, data)
        
    }
}
```

Sample Messaging Channel XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>SampleMessageChannel</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>Message Channel to pass data</description>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>lmsData</fieldName>
        <description>This is the field to pass data</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>xToAData</fieldName>
        <description>This is to pass number from X to A</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you're both a subscriber and a publisher, you're going to receive your own messages. As such, you need to remember to check if the expected data is being received. The following changes should fix your problem.

```
handleMessage(message) {
    if (message.lmsData) {
        this.recievedMessage = message.lmsData.value || 'NO Message published';
    }
}
```

...

```
subscribeTransfer() {
    this.subcription = subscribe(
        this.context,
        SAMPLEMC,
        (data) => {
            if (data.xToAData) {
                this.recievedData = data.xToAData.receivedNum
            }
        },
        { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
    );
}
```

Note that the "it only works one way" problem was occurring because you were getting errors like "unable to read 'value' from undefined", because you weren't checking if the top-level objects were populated. It so happened that it worked one way, but not the other, because of the order the subscriptions were being processed.